# vmware remote Linux vm interactive boot

Tags: linux, boot, virtual-machine, vmware

Is it possible to interactively boot a remote Linux based vmware vm?

If the vm is hosted locally, I can start it with my vmplayer and see the BIOS screen, then my Linux boot grub menu. I can then choose which boot entry to boot from interactively using arrow keys, then press enter to boot it.

If the vm is hosted remotely, would the above still be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have console access to the VM environment. Using the vSphere web client or thick client where it might end up living. With out that vSphere client access your hosed as far as I know.